# JSON: java.lang.Double null is converted to zero; How should I handle in client?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I have a client that makes AJAX requests. The Java application server creates a list of objects that have java.lang.Double instance fields. Depending on the request, some of these instance fields may be null on all the objects. But when the list of objects is converted (via JSONArray.fromObject) nulls are converted to zero.

So, on the client side, these show up as zero values to the user. How should I handle this so the user does not see these values? I would think it would be best stop the server from sending zero in the first place (perhaps by not sending the field), but I'm not sure how to do this cleanly with JSON. Less favorably, I could figure out someway on the client to know what was requested in the handler and prevent showing data unless the client requested. In that case, is there a way to get the HTTP request param data from the XMLHttpRequest object?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What library are you using to generate the JSON on the server?  Sound like this is an unboxing issue where Double is converted to double and the null is converted to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different JSON parser (Crockford's is one possibility).  That nulls as 0 stuff seems like a bug.

Comment: I'll try that out. I'm currently using net.sf.json-lib (group id), json-lib (artifact id) and version 2.3. Where would I get Crockford's parser? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (you'll also find a link to it on the official json.org, as it's one of only two JS parsers listed there)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I might be missing something. Crockford's code does not seem to be a Java to JSON library. I have no issues parsing JSON on the JavaScript side. The issue is transforming the Java objects into JSON.

Comment: ohhhhh I completely misunderstood.  The same idea could apply though (if you go to json.org you'll see they have multiple Java=>JSON libraries).  However, I read the javadoc on your library (specifically JSONArray, http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html), and it doesn't describe the behavior you're seeing.  Therefore, you might want to file a bug with them, or use the other fromObject signature (which lets you pass in a config argument; I didn't look at that Config extensively, but based on a quick look it seemed like it could solve this problem).

Comment: BTW, I just checked and we actually use the same library in our application, only we use an older version which doesn't have that fromObject method.  We instead just use the JSONObject constructor that takes a single object as an argument.  Not sure if your version has that constructor, or what the differences between that constructor and fromObject are ... but it's probably worth trying the constructor to see if it helps.